# Sending mail from Rails works at console but not in my application...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have a pretty simple Rails app and I want send an e-mail when a work request is created. I'm pretty new to Rails so I found some details on how to do it online. Set up a Mailer, configured it, etc. Set up my templates. Fine.

In my work_requests_controller.rb I have:

```
  def create
    @work_request = WorkRequest.new(params[:work_request])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @work_request.save
        # Tell the mailer to send a welcome Email after save
        PersonMailer.work_request_init_email(@work_request).deliver

        format.html... etc.
```

In know mailing is working because if I go to the Rails console, create WorkRequest object, and use that exact same line (PersonMailer.work...) it sends the mail just fine. But when I create a work request in my application no mail is received, no error is displayed in the browser or in logs/development.log.

In the server output I see the HTML version was rendered, and I see the info about the e-mail and it all looks both hunky and dory. Since I get no errors I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: Are you running your console in the same environment?

Comment: Yes, Kevin, the development environment in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I am officially an idiot. :-)

Working on a different problem, I was editing application.rb. I figured I needed to restart the server to make it see those changes. Suddenly, the e-mails work from inside the app.

D'oh! I did not realize (rookie mistake) that I needed to restart the server for the app to see the e-mail configuration I had placed in environment.rb yesterday. I never tried that for some reason.

I see now that and other components are run only when the server starts up. So of course, when I started up console of course it runs all the initializers and so the e-mail configuration was visible to it and the e-mails were sent.

So the answer is, restart your server, stupid. Well, anyway, at least it's working now...I'll take it where I can get it!

Comment: If it's any consolation, I'm an idiot, too. I had the same exact problem for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with moving your email command to your WorkRequest model as a 'after_create' action

```
after_create :send_init_email


def send_init_email
  PersonMailer.deliver_work_request_init_email(self)
end
```

See if that works, or aleast gives you a better error msg.

Comment: Didn't work. And interestingly now I don't even see the mail output in the logs. Here's what I see. You can see it rendering the e-mail templates, but before it actually showed the e-mail details in the log.

Comment: For some reason it won't let me post the logs? Basically I see  the post to save the new WorkRequest, I see it render the e-mail templates but then just redirects to the WorkRequest show page and I see no e-mail details.

Comment: good to see you got it working, I would still recommend putting the email send in your model instead of your controller.

Comment: I was thinking about that. Now I know I'm new but I am trying to be as Railish as possible and to me it does not seem that sending an e-mail is a Model thing. That seems to me more to be a Controller thing. The Model is responsible for reading, writing, and validating the data. Sending an e-mail is not affecting the data at all (well it's being read, but . . .) I could see using after_create modify some data or update the record with a date stamp or something like that, but sending an e-mail? I'd be interested to hear what others think about this.

Comment: Here's an interesting article with tons of comments I just came across. Looks like there is some room for argument but that most that I've read so far think it belongs in the model... http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2009/11/16/sending-email-controllers-versus-models

Comment: There is a saying in the MVC community... Keep your Models FAT, your Controllers SKINNY and your Views DUMB. As a general rule the more logic you can put in the model the easier the code will be to maintain and expand down the track. e.g. maybe down the track you will want to create auto generated WorkRequest's from somewhere else in your rails app and not just through the user submitting a form to the create action in the controller. If your email is in the controller and you create a new work request direct from the model the email won't get sent, but if it is in the model it will.

Comment: What about the argument that sending an e-mail is just another case of rendering a view? What about the objection someone makes in the thread that I created above that you might want to process a lot of new requests (say, loading old data) and not generate e-mails for them? I suppose in that case you could pass something to Model.new sendmail = true/false...?